# Python error - Can't redirect the url set up

Tags: python, flask

I have code as follow. The app should be redirected to `https://example.com?code={ cliient_id }` but it failed with the error.

The error is:

> redirect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

The code is below. Error is on the last line of extracted code.

```
client_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX'

@bp.route('/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def redirect():
    authorize_url = f"https://example.com?code={ cliient_id }"

    return redirect(authorize_url)
```

Comment: in the `redirect` function, why are you returning itself? are you trying to create an infinite recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing `redirect` from flask, but also defining your own function named `redirect`. Your new definition "wins", and your definition takes no arguments. Try naming your function `redirect_` instead (or any other name), e.g.

```
client_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX'

@bp.route('/redirect', methods=['GET'])
def redirect_():
    authorize_url = f"https://example.com?code={ cliient_id }"

    return redirect(authorize_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function, as defined, takes zero arguments:
*def redirect()*

However, its return value is the redirect function with an argument, redirect(**authorize_url**)